# Pandas remove time format from date object when json serializing

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I using pandas to get analytics based on date, where the time passed is datetime. When JSON serializing, the date object is converted to string including time like

```py
# Extract date from scan_time
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['scan_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.date

# Extract analytics
grouped_total = df.groupby('date').size().reset_index(name='total_count')
grouped_false = df[df['is_from_qr_code_scan'] == False].groupby('date').size().reset_index(name='false_count')
grouped_true = df[df['is_from_qr_code_scan'] == True].groupby('date').size().reset_index(name='true_count')

# Merge result
result = pd.merge(grouped_total, grouped_false, on='date', how='outer')
result = pd.merge(result, grouped_true, on='date', how='outer')

# Format date
# result['date'] = result['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Fill missing dates with 0
result = result.set_index('date')
date_range = pd.date_range(start=result.index.min(), end=result.index.max(), freq='D')
result = result.fillna(0)
result = result.reindex(date_range, fill_value=0)

count_total = result[['total_count']].reset_index().values.tolist()
count_url = result[['false_count']].reset_index().values.tolist()
count_qr = result[['true_count']].reset_index().values.tolist()

data = {
    'all': count_total,
   'qr': count_qr,
   'url': count_url
}
```

Output

```
{'all': [[Timestamp('2023-04-27 00:00:00'), 91],
  [Timestamp('2023-04-28 00:00:00'), 269],
  [Timestamp('2023-04-29 00:00:00'), 0],
  [Timestamp('2023-04-30 00:00:00'), 0],
  [Timestamp('2023-05-01 00:00:00'), 111],],
 'qr': [[Timestamp('2023-04-27 00:00:00'), 36.0],
  [Timestamp('2023-04-28 00:00:00'), 45.0],
  [Timestamp('2023-04-29 00:00:00'), 0.0],
  [Timestamp('2023-04-30 00:00:00'), 0.0],
  [Timestamp('2023-05-01 00:00:00'), 26.0],],
 'url': [[Timestamp('2023-04-27 00:00:00'), 55],
  [Timestamp('2023-04-28 00:00:00'), 224],
  [Timestamp('2023-04-29 00:00:00'), 0],
  [Timestamp('2023-04-30 00:00:00'), 0],
  [Timestamp('2023-05-01 00:00:00'), 85],]}
```

I only want date `2023-04-28` and not the time part in the final result to return in API response.

I tried using `result['date'] = result['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` but it gives error

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try converting the [*DatetimeIndex*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) to the desired format with [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) :

```
#... rest of code
result = result.reindex(date_range, fill_value=0)

result.index = result.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') # <-- add this line

count_total = result[['total_count']].reset_index().values.tolist()
#... rest of code
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Also why `count_qr` is filled with decimal 0 while others not?

Comment: I ignore how look like your dataset, so it's hard to tell why the column `true_count` of your dataframe `result` is cast to `float` (*maybe due to some missing values at a certain point of your code processing*) but you can try something like this : `count_qr = result[['true_count']].astype(int).reset_index().values.tolist()`. If you got an error, try with `.astype("Int64")`.

Comment: The values are just the count of rows in the database. Where there is no data in `grouped_true `, the field has a `nan` value which is then set as 0 using `fillna(0)`. Not sure why it is decimal, however, `.astype(int)` works.

Answer (score 0):

you should insert a line, where you should reset the index and then take the date only. An example of your code is below:

```
result.reset_index(inplace=True)
result['index'] = result['index'].dt.date
count_total = result[['index','total_count']].values.tolist()
count_url = result[['index','false_count']].values.tolist()
count_qr = result[['index','true_count']].values.tolist()

data = {
    'all': count_total,
   'qr': count_qr,
   'url': count_url
}
data
```

This code should be place after the line:

```
result = result.reindex(date_range, fill_value=0)
```

The output would be like this:

```
{'all': [[datetime.date(2023, 5, 6), 1440],
  [datetime.date(2023, 5, 7), 1440],
  [datetime.date(2023, 5, 8), 1]],
 'qr': [[datetime.date(2023, 5, 6), 1440],
  [datetime.date(2023, 5, 7), 1440],
  [datetime.date(2023, 5, 8), 1]],
 'url': [[datetime.date(2023, 5, 6), 1440],
  [datetime.date(2023, 5, 7), 1440],
  [datetime.date(2023, 5, 8), 1]]}
```